# Borrar rows data table cuando encuentre un valor en x columna

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hola actualmente estoy iniciando con data table, la situacion es que solo logro llenar una tabla, y hacer que aparezca un boton cuando la columna **Respuesta** contiene un valor diferente de **Success** lo que quiero hacer es que al encontrar la primer respuesta diferente de **Success** elimine las rows restantes acontinuacion anexo dos imagenes la primera es como se muestra y la segunda como deberia de mostrarse

```
var tabla=  $("#tabla-respuesta-plataforma").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'url',
                dataSrc: "",
                data: { ot: otSeleccionado, fol: folio },
                beforeSend: function () { },
                complete: function () { },
            },

            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            paging: true,
            paginate: true,
            lengthChange: false,
            pageLength: 10,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            columns: [
                { data: "plataforma" },
                { data: "comando" },
                { data: "respuesta" },
                { data: "idcomando" },
                { data: "reintentar","render": function (data, type, row) {

                    if ((row.respuesta != "Success")) {


                        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-estilo' style='border: 2px solid red'>Reintentar</button>";


                        } else {

                            return "";
                        }

                    }
                }
            ],


        });
            /* 
          var tabla3css = document.getElementById("tabla-respuesta-plataforma"); //esta es una variable global solo anexo aqui para explicar de donde viene

//con esto deberia eliminarse las row fila=(tabla3css.rows.length)-2;
                    columna=(tabla3css.rows[0].cells.length)-1;
                    if ((tabla.cell(fila,2).data())!="Success"){
                    tabla.cell(fila,columna).data('<div style="width:20px"><a><button type="submit" onclick="Reintentos()" class="btn btn-info hb">REINTENTAR <i class="fa fa-refresh" ></i></button></a></div>');*/
                }


        $("#tabla-respuesta-plataforma").closest("div").addClass("tabla-scroll");
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
```

[image: asi es como se muestra]
[image: asi es como se deberia de ver]

Comment: a mi parecer deberias utilizar el metodo **[remove](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove())** y aqui hay un [post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36642/how-to-remove-a-row-before-it-is-rendered) en el foro que trata sobre el mismo problema que tienes

Comment: ya lo intente con el metodo remove antes pero elimina todo, y no respeta el if con el cual compruebo :/ pero gracias!

Comment: @jonadab_mg, Si lo que quieres es visualizar los datos que sean diferentes de 'success', simplemente has eso desde tu consulta, asi cuando pintes tu datos solo mostraras lo diferentes de success y listo, no te "complicas" haciendo validaciones que no son tan necesarias

Answer (score 0):

bueno la solucion que encontre fue la siguiente:(aclaro que no es la mas limpia pero ayudo en lo que queria hacer)

agregue estas variables globales

```
    var tabla3css = document.getElementById("tabla-respuesta-plataforma");
    var columna;
    var fila;
```

agregue estas propiedades propias del datatable

```
initComplete: function() {
            fila=(tabla3css.rows.length);
            columna=(tabla3css.rows[0].cells.length-1);
            if(tabla3css.rows[fila-1].cells[columna-2].innerHTML!="Success"){
            tabla3css.rows[fila-1].cells[columna].innerHTML="<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-estilo'style='border: 2px solid red'>Reintentar</button>";
            }
        },
```